# Разбор входящих данных регулярными выражениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужно разбить(split) входящую строку в цикле, несколько примеров входящих данных:

```
Bla bla text text 4544it   fh-SDE-c2030/c2025/c2020/ jk-ADV-c2230/c2225/c2220 (Text)
Text (ds) bla bla text text, text
Bla, bla. text text 4544it (Text)
Bla bla text text 4544it (dfs) fh-SDE-c2030/c2025/c2020/ jk-ADV-c2230/c2225/c2220 (Text
```

Вопрос, как мне достать данные, что бы получилось что-то в этом роде:

```
fh-SDE-c2030
c2025
c2020
jk-ADV-c2230
c2225
c2220
```

Так же хочу уточнить, что данные могут содержать кириллицу, спецсимволы и между символом `/` содержаться пробелы (пример: `c2020/ jk-ADV-c2230`), перед и за символом `/` пробелы нужно удалять

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/RJVj5b/3 Так подойдет?

Comment: Похоже, но не совсем то что нужно, данное решение не универсальное. Оно не найдет ничего если например будет `Text DD2030d/SS2025nwdf`

Comment: Тоесть, как я понимаю содержимое между слешами может быть вообще рандомно?

Comment: Да может быть абсолютно разные данные, мне же нужно находить `/` и обрабатывать их! Вот еще пару примеров входящих данных: `Text, T text - text (text45) TEXT D4400/4400dn/P5555wwd`, `Text, Text (Text)`, `Text, Text  TEXT E1100/F98756dddd/ S456aaa, Text 666 (Text)` и т.п. единственное на что можно опираться это символ `/` и мне нужны те данные которые находится по бокам т.е. `Text HFD65666d+/ ESDO 456` должен получить `HFD65666d+` и `ESDO 456`

Comment: Вот так посмотрите https://regex101.com/r/RJVj5b/5

Comment: Пытаюсь разобрать в python строку `ФИЛЬТР ВХОДЯЩИХ ДАННЫХ. iR-ADV-6055/6065/6075/ iR-ADV-6255/dsdsd-456d/6265/6275/ iR-ADV-8105/8095/8085/ iR-ADV-8205/8295/8285` на выходе получаю `iR-ADV-6055/6065/6075/`, не пойму почему остальное не выводит((. Вот сам код `re.search(r'\s(\S+?)(\s+)?/(\s+)?(\S+?)(\s+)?/(\s+)?(\S+?)(\s|/)', data)`

Comment: Потому, что `iR-ADV-6255/dsdsd-456d/6265/6275/` не подходит под шаблон, а для того, что-бы найти **ВСЕ** используйте `findall`

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста, что генерит такой затейливый вывод, порой бывает так, что люди регулярками пытаются разобрать то, для чего уже придуманы инструменты (ярким примером тому html, xml, json и т.д.)

Comment: К сожалению такой вывод не от меня зависит, поэтому приходится разбирать, что дают)). Это не стандартизированный код, поэтому и решил прибегнуть к регулярным выражениям. Спасибо за помощь, решил реализовать `text4 = re.split(r'/', data)
    start_el = re.findall(r'\S+$', text4[0])
    end_el = re.findall(r'^\S+', text4[-1])
    start_el.reverse()
    end_el.reverse()
    text4[0] = ' '.join(start_el)
    text4[-1] = ' '.join(end_el)
    print(text4)`